# Doubts with Python

Tags: python

I have a question. Here you have part of my code for a better understanding:

```
def client ():
    A=[]
    B = open("clientes.txt", "r")
    user = input("To begin, enter your ID number: ")
    for line in B:
        C = line.split("$")
        A.append(C)
    for i in range (len(A)):
        if A[i][0]==user:
```

and then I have another function, here is it:

```
def clientpersonalinfo ():
    A=[]
    B=[]
    C = open("accounts.txt", "r")
    D = open("clients.txt", "r")
    for line in C:
        E=line.split("$")
        A.append(E)
    for line in D:
        F=line.split("$")
        B.append(F)
    for i in range (len(A)):
        ***if user==A[i][1]:***
```

The question is if there is any method in which i can re-use the first input. As you see if I run this, there will be an error saying that the name "user" is not defined.

So I want to know if I can recall the user input that I first used in clients () and re-use it in my clientpersonalinfo () function.

Thanks for your help!!

Thanks to all those who helped me! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Please write a title that actually describes your question.

Comment: You need to tell us more what your code is all about. Also, A, B, C are not valid variable names in Python (well, technically they are, but nobody names things that way).

Comment: It really annoys me to see all of these arbitrary A,B,C variables and have to scan around the entire code to remember the context.

Comment: Declare `user` in global scope. i.e., before defining those functions.

Answer (score 2):

Please review the python docs on how to write functions with arguments: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

```
def myFunction1():
    user = "foo"
    return user

def myFunction2(user):
    print user

user = myFunction1()
myFunction2(user)
```

Ideally you would organize a nice class structure, instead of using globals everywhere which I think is messy. Its a good sign that you should indeed be using a class when all of your functions end up needing to share some kind of state and you think you might need to start defining a ton of globals:

```
class Client(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.userId = None

    def getClient(self):
        self.userId = raw_input("To begin, enter your ID number: ")

    def parseClientInfo(self):
        # do something with self.userId
        print self.userId 

    def clientPersonalInfo(self):
        # do something with self.userId
        print self.userId
```

Please note that this class is a really simple example.

Comment: I think, as the user didn't mention what exactly `client()` does, its not really appropriate to return `user`. Probably, he could declare in global scope.

Comment: @Surya: Thats an assumption as there isn't enough context in his question to know either way. You might as well suggest he should write a class and store `user` as a member attribute. So, we disagree

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse whatever you want, you just have to store it somewhere that is visible to both funcitons. You could make a class and put the information in a field or you could return it from the function and pass it on when you call the other function. Global variables are bad style, but that's doable too.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the content of "user" (which would be better named "user_input" or some such), one way is to return the content of "user" along with whatever else you are returning in client(), perhaps in a tuple, and then passing it to clientpersonalinfo() as an argument, i.e. clientpersonalinfo(user).  Another way is to put the code for getting "user" higher up in the hierarchy so that user exists in the function that calls both client() and clientpersonalinfo(), and then passing it as an argument to both functions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then I think that the best thing for you to do is to take the input call out of the first function and change the function definitions of both functions to take the user as an argument. The code would look something like:

```
def client(user):
    clients = []
    with open("clientes.txt",'r') as f:
        for client in f:
            clients.append(client.split('$'))
    for client in clients:
        if client[0] == user:
            ...

user = raw_input("To begin, enter your ID number: ")
client(user)
```

and the other would be similar. There are a couple of changes from how you handle things. It is recommended that use use the "with open" form since it handles problems better than just opening the file, for instance. Also, naming variables so that the name is relevant to what you are doing makes your code easier to read, so avoid using names like A. Finally, you should use raw_input rather than input in general. The input function evaluates what is input by the user, which means that a user could call some code which is generally not what you want. The raw_input function returns a string which contains what the user put in.